# ¿Cómo crear claves de diccionario automáticamente y sin repetición?

Tags: python

Tengo un diccionario que almacena nombre, appellido y edad de una persona. A continuación creo una función para añadir nuevas personas al diccionario, de manera que se creen automáticamente nuevas claves del tipo persona2, persona3, persona4 etc; según la cantidad de claves existentes en el diccionario. Aquí el código, luego el problema.

```
info= {'persona1': ['Ana', 'López', 37]}

def añadir ():
    cantidad= len(info)
    n= cantidad + 1
    info['persona' + str(n)]= [nombre, apellido, edad]
```

El código me funciona bien, el problema surge si quiciera eliminar una clave, por ejemplo la persona3 de 4. Si luego quiciera añadir una nueva persona, la función contaría 3 claves y por tanto crearía la "persona4", el inconveniente es que esta clave ya existe y tendría un error.
Por tanto mi pregunta es ¿cómo podría crear claves automáticamente que evite la repetición de las mismas?

Comment: ¿Por qué tiene que ser un diccionario y no una lista? La llave que usas parece no tener ningún significado especial ni relación con el valor que almacena.

Comment: Como bien señala @CandidMoe, deberías replantearte la forma en que estás estructurando esa data. No conozco tu caso de uso, pero normalmente al guardar registros de ese tipo se usa una lista con diccionarios en ella (no al revés, como estás haciendo). Es decir, sería algo tipo: `info = [{'nombre': 'Ana', 'apellido': 'López'}, {'nombre': 'Pedro', 'apellido': 'Pérez'}, ... ]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
info= {'persona1': ['Ana', 'López', 37]}

n = 1

def añadir (nombre,apellido,edad):
    cantidad= len(info)
    global n
    n+=1
    info['persona' + str(n)]= [nombre, apellido, edad]
    
añadir("Juan","Rios",31)
añadir("Carlos","Burgos",31)
info.pop("persona1")
añadir("Camila","Sanchez",28)
print(info)
```

Si le agregas una variable global que vaya aumentando de uno en uno, nunca se va a repetir el nombre de la llave del diccionario.

Si lo que quieres unicamente es revisar que no se repita puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
llave = 'persona' + str(n)
    for key in info.keys():
        if llave == key:
            print("llave repetida")
```

Answer (score 0):

Este es un complemento (mejora) a la respuesta de Juan Carlos.

En lugar de usar una variable global `n`, puedes usar un atributo de la función para guarda esa misma información.

Un atributo de función viene siendo como una variable local persistente a través de distintas ejecuciones. La ventaja es que siendo local, no puede ser cambiada por error por otra parte del código.

Los atributos de la  función `añadir` se nombran anteponiendo el nombre de la función al nombre del atributo. Así, en lugar de usar `n` (variable global) podemos usar `añadir.n` (atributo de función).

El detalle es que `añadir.n` no existe al principio. Si tratas de usarla sin más, se producira un error:

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'n'
```

El patrón a usar es intentar usarla, y si se produce el error, inicializarla:

```
def añadir(nombre, apellido, edad):
    try:
        añadir.n += 1
    except AttributeError:
        añadir.n = 1

    cantidad = len(info)
    info['persona' + str(añadir.n)] = [nombre, apellido, edad]
```

Adicionalmente, desde otras partes del programa puedes accesar y/o modificar dicha variable usando la misma sintaxis:

```
añadir.n = 0
```

Es útil cuando quieres reinicializar/usar la variable fuera de la función:

```
añadir("Juan", "Rios", 31)
añadir("Carlos", "Burgos", 31)
info.pop("persona1")
añadir("Camila", "Sanchez", 28)
print(info)

print(añadir.n)  # -> 3, el valor actual de n dentro de añadir.
```